# URL Rewrite in PHP like in Smarty Template

Tags: php, url-rewriting, smarty, friendly-url

I am banging my head from a couple of days to use the URL rewriting for a core php website. Previously the website was developed using smarty, but due to some limitations, I am redoing it in core PHP. The problem is that smarty is using some templates code to create the Pretty URL's which I am not able to do in core PHP. Like in this example.
http://amitgharat.blogspot.com/

Is any body came across this kind of problem and save me, or any idea or suggestion please. I will be really thank full.

Regards,

Comment: Some examples of `some templates code to create the Pretty URL's` would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need need is a "front controller" ref: http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_front_controller_and_php

Essentially what happens is this:

- Assuming your site will have this url structure:

  http://www.example.com/page/1
- A .htaccess file redirects all requests to a file (index.php). You can of course write your .htaccess file so that files that do exist with certain extensions (.jpg etc) are not redirected.
- In your index.php you can access the "page/1" part from your url via the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variable.

When you then do from there is up to you. For example, you might break that up into an array using `explode()`,  do some more parsing and finally dispatch the requested call.

If you haven't already looked at the mvc pattern, I reckon it would be worth while looking at that.

Having said that, there are quite a few nice PHP frameworks out there (code igniter, symfony, etc) which can allow you to code up that site quickly.

Comment: The best solution, I had been found was http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Apache/Using-ForceType-For-Nicer-Page-URLs/ May be it will help someone.

Comment: Your phppatterns.com link is dead.